# Hidden UIImageView while click the table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application in one place i am display the `UIImage` and lable in a table view cell.It is working fine. while click on the row i try to hidden one UIImage view and display another UIImage view.

Code i try is

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"AddFrdsGroup";
    AddFriendsCell *cell = (AddFriendsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddFriendsCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    if(cell.chkAddFrdsYes.hidden==YES)
    {
        cell.chkAddFrdsNo.hidden=YES;
        cell.chkAddFrdsYes.hidden=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.chkAddFrdsNo.hidden=YES;
        cell.chkAddFrdsYes.hidden=NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: explain little bit more?

Comment: i am binding table view cell to table view. It is working fine on page load. After that if click on the cell its want to hidden one UIImage view and display Other UIImage View.

Comment: Why you are using both `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier]` and `NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddFriendsCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];` in didSelectRow?

Comment: for getting the cell

Comment: I think you are doing completely wrong. Only change UIImage  for UIImageView.

Comment: Use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to get Cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message is not very clear but i'll try to help you with what I could understand.
You need to get the cell you selected, not create or dequeue a new one.
Try this instead.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AddFriendsCell *cell = (AddFriendsCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.chkAddFrdsYes.hidden==YES)
    {
        cell.chkAddFrdsNo.hidden=YES;
        cell.chkAddFrdsYes.hidden=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.chkAddFrdsNo.hidden=YES;
        cell.chkAddFrdsYes.hidden=NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, save the indexPath of the row/cell selected in instance variable/property and call the reloadData method of table view. In tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: implementation (In table view datasource), do the hidden/unhidden activity of image views.